# How to search and find from one data-frame and substitute in another?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I have two data frames as following:

```
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 507, 505), b = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
df2 = data.frame(A = c(501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507), 
                 B = c(601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607))
```

I want to find the values of `df1$b` for which `df2$A` is equal to `df1$a`. In this simple example I'm looking for 50 and 60 in which `df1$a == df2$A`.

I have tried the following:

```
df1$b[which(df2$a %in% df1$A)]
```

which doesn't always returns the values in order for bigger datasets. For example, when I use the following analogous with above with more sophisticated datasets i.e. `FTN` and `top_list` similar to `df1` and `df2` as:

```
  top_list$performance <- FTN$YIELD_MEAN_NBR[which(as.character(FTN$PLOT_GRID_ID) %in% top_list$gridID)]
```

The following lines don't return the same values as I would expect.

```
  ID = "62927530"
  FTN$YIELD_MEAN_NBR[FTN$PLOT_GRID_ID == ID]
  top_list$performance[top_list$gridID == ID]
```

This puzzles me!

Comment: I know how to do it by a loop btw. I'm looking for a at-once solve applicable to big data frames. Thanks!

Comment: Why should they return the same value? They are two columns from two different data frames. I don't see direct relationship between them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `df1$a` in `df2$A`, not the other way around:

```
df1$b[df1$a %in% df2$A]
# [1] 50 60
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that works. However the issue is that it doesn't always return the things in order. I modified the question to communicate the issue better.